# Extract word embeddings from word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

Good evening,  I have a relatively simple question that primarily comes from my inexperience with python.  I would like to extract word embeddings for a list of words.  Here I have created a simple list:

```
list_word = [['Word'],
 ['ant'],
 ['bear'],
 ['beaver'],
 ['bee'],
 ['bird']]
```

Then load gensim and other required libraries:

```
#import tweepy           # Obtain Tweets via API
import re               # Obtain expressions 
from gensim.models import Word2Vec    #Import gensim Word2Fec
```

Now when I use the Word2Vec function I run the following:

```
#extract embedding length 12
model = Word2Vec(list_word, min_count = 3, size = 12)
print(model)
```

When the model is run I then see that the vocab size is 1, when it should not be.  The output is the following:
Word2Vec(vocab=1, size=12, alpha=0.025)

I imagine that the imported data is not in the correct format and could use some advise or even example code on how to transform it into the correct format.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you actually showing us your data? You define `list_word2` (which only has 6 words and they only occur once) but then you run training on `list_word` and manage to get a single word which occurs >=min_count (= 3) times. Also, your data is way too small. Either download and use pretrained word-vectors, or get.a much larger training-set.

Comment: Oh interesting, i  was operating under the assumption that when you use word2vec as I had it that it will pull the embeddings from pretrained models.  My real data is a list of ~1600 nouns that I am trying to get word embeddings for.  Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Well [`model = Word2Vec(list_word, ...)`](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.__init__.html) *trains* word-vectors from your data and using whatever parameters you pass. But the output will suck for such small input, so recommend you download and use pretrained word-vectors. See the doc and tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list_data`, 6 sentences each with a single word, is insufficient to train `Word2Vec`, which requires a lot of varied realistic text data. Among other problems:

- words that only appear once will be ignored due to the `min_count=3` setting (& it's not a good idea to lower that parameter)
- single-word sentences have none of the nearby-words contexts the algorithm uses
- getting good 'dense' vectors requires a vocabulary far larger than the vector-dimensionality, and many varied examples of each word's use with other words

Try using a larger dataset, and you'll see more realistic results. Also, enabling Python logging at the INFO level will show a lot of progress as the code runs - and perhaps hint at issues, as you notice steps happening with or without reasonable counts & delays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I stated to smsci i was operating under the assumption that using word2vec as i have in the above code pulled the pretrained models embeddings.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: Nope - nothin in your code loads any pretrained models, and supplying `list_word2` to the constructor means you're supplying a corpus of training texts. (For the case where you did get 1 word, maybe that time your `list_word2` was a simple list of strings, so each string was interpreted as a sentence, so each character looked like a word - and the one "word" of the letter `e` was the one vector created?)

Answer (score 0):

model = Word2Vec(list_word, min_count = 3, size = 12)
you can use vector_size  for setting dimensionality